# Probability with Distributions

Tags: probability

A bin has 10 red balls and 8 blue balls. We randomly draw out 6 balls, one at a time, without replacement. What is the probability, that, at some point, we choose two consecutive balls that are red?

This is an interesting distribution problem, and here is how I started. So first I did $\binom{10+8}{6} = \binom{18}{6}$ which is the number of ways to pick 6 balls out of 18 without regard to order. Now I think I should do casework based on the amount of red balls I draw? Obviously 0 or 1 red balls won't work.

How should I continue?

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to start by finding the probability that no red balls are adjacent.

There are $\binom{18}{6} 6!$ possible sequences of the selected balls, all of which we assume are equally likely.

Suppose there are $i$ red balls among the $6$ selected.  If no red balls are adjacent, then we must have $0 \le i \le 3$, and the positions of the red balls can be chosen in $\binom{6-i+1}{i}$ ways.  Once the positions of the $i$ red balls are chosen, they can be selected and sequenced in $\binom{10}{i} i!$ ways, and the $6-i$ blue balls can be selected and sequenced in $\binom{8}{6-i} (6-i)! $ ways.  So the total number of sequences in which no red balls are adjacent is 
$$N = \sum_{i=0}^3 \binom{6-i+1}{i} \; \binom{10}{i} i! \; \binom{8}{6-i} (6-i)!$$
and the probability that no red balls are adjacent is 
$$p = \frac{N} {\binom{18}{6} 6!} = 0.217195$$
So the probability that at least two red balls are adjacent is $1-p = \boxed{0.782805}.
$

Answer (score 0):

I would attempt this problem using the **method of complementary set**. Essentially, I try to find the number of ways of drawing 6 balls such that 2 consecutive red balls do **not** appear, and subtract this probability from 1

Now, if I draw a red ball at a particular point, the next ball I draw **must** be a blue ball (so that no two consecutive red balls are drawn)

Using casework, we can consider the possibilities for each ball (either red or blue), which is not as difficult as it may seem given that after a red ball there must be a blue ball

Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 0):

The six balls that you draw in terms of Red and Blue are

Case 1: R - 6, B - 0:  The probability that such a sequence of draw $P_1 = \frac{{10\choose6}{8\choose0}}{{18\choose6}}$

Case 2: R - 5, B - 1 : $P_2 = \frac{{10\choose5}{8\choose1}}{{18\choose6}}$

Case 3: R - 4, B - 2 : $P_3 = \frac{{10\choose4}{8\choose2}}{{18\choose6}}$

Case 4: R - 3, B - 3 : $P_4 = \frac{{10\choose3}{8\choose3}}{{18\choose6}}$

Case 5: R - 2, B - 4 : $P_5 = \frac{{10\choose2}{8\choose4}}{{18\choose6}}$

Case 6: R - 1, B - 5

Case 7: R - 0, B - 6

In cases 1, 2, 3, there at some point you would have two consecutive reds drawn.

Only in cases 4 and 5 do you have times when you don't have two consecutive reds and  the probability of that would be $PP_4= \frac{{4\choose3}}{{6\choose3}}$ and in case 5,$PP_5= \frac{{5\choose2}}{{6\choose2}}$and 1 minus that will be the probability that you will find atleast one time two consecutive red.  In case 4, it is $1-\frac{1}{5}$   and in case 5, it is $1-\frac{10}{15}$.  IN the last two cases there are no ways to have two consecutive reds.

Thus the required probability $= P_1+P_2+P_3+P_4\times(1-PP_4)+P_5\times(1-PP_5).=0.78280543$